# Scala, Pattern matching with no extraction

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Im looking to create a pattern matcher which doesnt require value extraction, and havent found a very satisfying way of doing this. Suppose I have the following ***illustrative*** example:

I want to match on Any being an Int

```
a:Any match {
  case IsAnInt => println(s"$a is an int")
}
```

Now the closest I can get is either boolean

```
a:Any match {
  case IsAnInt(true) => println(s"$a is an int")
}

object IsAnInt { 
  def unapply(a:Any):Option[Boolean] = Some(a.isInstanceOf[Int]) 
}
```

or unit

```
a:Any match {
  case IsAnInt(()) => println(s"$a is an int")
}

object IsAnInt { 
  def unapply(a:Any):Option[Unit] = if (a.isInstanceOf[Int]) Some(()) else None
}
```

Which I can do, but isnt nearly as cool...
Is there any trick Im not aware of to achieve the first case?

(just to clarify the example is a simplification, I'm not looking for ways to identify an int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean extractor, i.e. an extractor that just returns a boolean (instead of an Option) to indicate whether it matches:

```
object IsAnInt {
  def unapply(a : Any) : Boolean = a.isInstanceOf[Int]
}

val x : Any = 3
x  match {
  case IsAnInt() => println("Is an int")
  case _ => println("Is not an int")
}
```

You still have the parenthesis to seperate matching the object from the extractor though.

Answer (score 3):

Try pattern matching on the type like this,

```
(1: Any) match {
  case v: Int => println(s"$v is an int")
  case ______ => println("not an int")
}
```